# Kubernetes pod not created for service

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes service for jenkins-agent.

But as I can see there is no pod created for that service. How can I initiate pod creation from the existing service?

This is how my service configuration looks like:

```
Name:              ci-jenkins-agent
Namespace:         ci
Labels:            app=ci-jenkins
                   chart=jenkins-0.35.1
                   component=ci-jenkins-master
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          component=ci-jenkins-master
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                199.62.116.92
Port:              slavelistener  50000/TCP
TargetPort:        50000/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: You need to appply a pod yaml to create a pod

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu The problem is that I do not have a pod yaml file (since this setup is already working like this - I am debugging it). Any chance that I can export pod configuration from kubectl somehow? I thought the configuration will be under service somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pods behind a service is decided by matching `Selector` of service with `label` of pods. So you need to get the existing pods with the label `component=ci-jenkins-master`

```
kubectl get pods -l component=ci-jenkins-master -n ci -o yaml > pod.yaml
```

But looking at the service `Endpoints` does not have any Pod IP which means service does not have any backend pod probably because there is no pod running with label `component=ci-jenkins-master`

Comment: there is no "component" label in mine