# How to create Pods for a Service?

Tags: openshift

I have a Service that has no Pods. How do I give the Service a Pod?

I deployed a Service "user-service" that initially had some Pods but they crashed and eventually were automatically removed. Now when I look for Pods I see error "No Pods found".

How do I create a new Pod for this service so I can read the logs and try to find why it's crashing?

I read this but my Service doesn't have a "component" label
[Kubernetes pod not created for service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63777419/kubernetes-pod-not-created-for-service)

Comment: please reformat your question, as it is not clear what you what you wish to achieve.

Comment: It's a simple question. I have a Service with no Pods. How do I create a Pod for that Service? I want to see the logs

Comment: provide the question with your manifests/yaml files and we can take a better look at your problem

Comment: I don't own the code/yaml so I can't post it. I want to know in general how a Pod is created for a service.

Answer (score 2):

`Pods` are not "created" by a`Service`...

You create`pods`, either explicitly or via a kubernetes's "controller" (`Deployment`, `StatefulSet`, `Job`,`Daemonset`...), then you configure the`Service` to "point to" pods, via a selector

There is a misconception here on k8s concepts

So in your case, you need to find the controller that created the pods initially, or find the manifest of the pod if it was not linked to a controller

From [the kubernetes doc:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

> Service: An abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service.

> In Kubernetes, a Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set of Pods and a policy by which to access them (sometimes this pattern is called a micro-service). The set of Pods targeted by a Service is usually determined by a selector

Answer (score 0):

Service resource has a selector to find pods to forward traffic.
Following is an example to find Pods which has the label `deployment: sample`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample
spec:
  selector:
    deployment: sample
...
```

But, I think expose deployment with `oc expose` command is easy way to create service for Pods.